# How to define target devices for an app in Google Developer Console

Tags: android

I would like to distribute my app for only tablets. 
I know I could define supported screens in the Manifest.xml, but if possible I would like to enable/disable screensizes in the developer console. This is much more flexible for me.

I also know that I could enable/disable specific devices for an app, but this is too time costly.

Is this possible in any way ?

Comment: the best way, really is to rely on the screensize in Manifest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible in any way ?

No. Your app will be made accessible to devices based on your AndroidManifest.xml requirements e.g., screen sizes, camera required etc etc.

Your only options are enabling/disabling devices as you mentioned or to periodically upload a new version of your APK with an updated AndroidManifest.xml file.